# Is there an easy way to move a file to a different folder in dbt Cloud?

Tags: dbt

Is there an easy way to move a file to a different folder in dbt Cloud, without having to create a new file of the same name in the new folder, copy/paste from the old file, and delete the old file, which is a pain.

Is there a good reason I should NOT do this? I assume my refs still work as long as the filename remains the same, and I don't have any specific folder logic tied to this file.

For example, say I have my_model.sql in my 'staging' folder and I want to simply move it to my 'mart' folder instead. In this example I'd like to do this to reflect that my file is really a more 'stable' mart-type table file vs a staging view. I realize I can just change the materialization type, but I'm doing this more to organize things clearly. Thanks!

Comment: Don't think you can do that in dbt Cloud... unless you have access to a bash terminal (which I am afraid you don't), then you could use the 'mv' command which does exactly what you just described :)

Comment: Turns out you're incorrect @AleixCC per Logan B's answer to use the rename function to change the filepath. Thanks though for taking a guess and suggesting the scripting workaround!

Comment: Definitely! TIL about the rename function :) Was not aware of that, sorry for the misleading comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to move a file in the cloud IDE for dbt is not 100% obvious. You can use the rename function to move a file to another location.

Click on the drop down next to the file name, then select "Rename." That will open a file path and you can change where the file lives from there by typing in the new folder's name.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Yes, it didn't even occur to me to edit the filepath using rename. For the win!

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I have found to do this is...not using DBT Cloud, but using github desktop (no command line needed).

1. Create a new branch
2. Open repository in github
3. View files in your file explorer
4. Move files or directory locally
5. Upload to github
6. Push to origin for the branch you created
7. Open a pull request
8. Merge

Depending on what the file or directory is you may find the creating a new branch and opening  PR to be overkill. For my specific project there is a lot of legacy organization and models that we aren't totally sure don't have downstream dependencies, so creating a new branch for this allowed me to test run all of our models.

Hope this helps!